# Getting XML without preprocessing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

This is a weird one, sorry. I'm trying to get data from an [API that returns malformed XML](http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=33381). In particular, each of many `<episode>` has its own `<title>` tag which, when processed by `$.get` or `$.ajax`, all get pushed to the `<head>` of the document.

However, I know this isn't the XML that the API is delivering - if you open the [link](http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=33381) in Chrome or whatever, you can see the individual `<title>` tags. Something in jQuery is preprocessing the XML before I can read it. How do I stop it?

**My Code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=33381',
    dataType: "text",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**The Response**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link/>
        <title>Pilot</title>
        <link/><link/><link/><link/><link/><link/><link/><link/><link/><link/><link/>
    </head>
<body>


<show>
<name>Rick and Morty</name>
...etc
```

I know the XML is bad, but it's all I have. I'd be happy to get the XML as plaintext, run a regex to fix it, and reprocess it as XML. But I don't know how to get it as plaintext -- every time I ask for `dataType: 'text'`, it seems preprocessed, with the weirdness presented above. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try changing it to `dataType: "XML",`

Comment: Hi @adeneo, I did :( It renders it as XML, which induces that same error.

Comment: You can try use the `converters` option, or the `dataFilter`, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/5ufdkm6r/**

Comment: Did you try a server-side approach? Fetch it server-side, fix it, then serve it to your app.

Comment: @peterKA that's what I'd do normally - I know PHP's `json_encode` doesn't have this bug - but unfortunately this app doesn't have a server. I'm hosting it on GitHub Pages.

Comment: I see; that's a tough one. I wonder if you can use an intermediate server script to  fetch, fix, and convert to jsonp, which your app can consume.

Comment: Maybe it's just me ... but I can't even visit `http://services.tvrage.com/`

Comment: @Meeseeks no, the whole service has been down for some time. No idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

For me is responding correct (chrome, mozila)

1. go here: http://services.tvrage.com/
2. Open console, In console, execute your code:

   $.ajax({url: 'http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=33381',
       dataType: "text",
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
       }
   });

and the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>


<Show>
<name>Rick and Morty</name>
<totalseasons>2</totalseasons>
<Episodelist>

<Season no="1">
<episode><epnum>1</epnum><seasonnum>01</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM100</prodnum><airdate>2013-12-02</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065427946</link><title>Pilot</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>2</epnum><seasonnum>02</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM101</prodnum><airdate>2013-12-09</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065433545</link><title>Lawnmower Dog</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>3</epnum><seasonnum>03</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM105</prodnum><airdate>2013-12-16</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065433546</link><title>Anatomy Park</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>4</epnum><seasonnum>04</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM103</prodnum><airdate>2014-01-13</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065450389</link><title>M. Night Shaym-Aliens!</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>5</epnum><seasonnum>05</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM104</prodnum><airdate>2014-01-20</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065450390</link><title>Meeseeks and Destroy</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>6</epnum><seasonnum>06</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM102</prodnum><airdate>2014-01-27</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065450391</link><title>Rick Potion #9</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>7</epnum><seasonnum>07</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM107</prodnum><airdate>2014-03-10</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065501839</link><title>Raising Gazorpazorp</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>8</epnum><seasonnum>08</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM108</prodnum><airdate>2014-03-17</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065504277</link><title>Rixty Minutes</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>9</epnum><seasonnum>09</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM109</prodnum><airdate>2014-03-24</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065504278</link><title>Something Ricked This Way Comes</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>10</epnum><seasonnum>10</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM106</prodnum><airdate>2014-04-07</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065504279</link><title>Close Rick-Counters of the Rick Kind</title></episode>
<episode><epnum>11</epnum><seasonnum>11</seasonnum><prodnum>RAM110</prodnum><airdate>2014-04-14</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065531436</link><title>Ricksy Business</title></episode>
</Season>

<Season no="2">
<episode><epnum>12</epnum><seasonnum>01</seasonnum><prodnum></prodnum><airdate>2015-07-26</airdate><link>http://www.tvrage.com/rick-and-morty/episodes/1065808803</link><title>Season 2, Episode 1</title></episode>
</Season>

</Episodelist>

</Show>
```

Use fiddler or wire-shark to see if loss/alteration of data take place in your browser or the response is incorrect.